# Server side column alignment

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, datatables, server-side

I'm having problems with how I should fix my column filters' alignment
After i put a non database column which will include my CRUD, My column filters were not properly functioning

```
while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    $row[0] = "<a href='new_position.php?CandidateCode=".$aRow['CandidateCode']."' ><img src='../img/assign.png' style='width: 20px; height: 20px;' title='Assign to a Position'/></a>";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "Action" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}
```

[image]

my first name column search is searching from the last name column